# Puzzling performance difference between mac and a relatively powerful desktop

Tags: c++, performance, c++11

My original intention for writing this piece of code is to measure performance difference when an entire array is operated on by a function vs operating individual elements of an array.

i.e. comparing the following two statements:

```
function_vector(x, y, z, n);
```

vs

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        function_scalar(x[i], y[i], z[i]);
}
```

where `function_*` does some substantial but identical calculations.

With `-ffast-math` turned on, the scalar version is roughly 2x faster on multiple machines I have tested on.

However, whats puzzling is the comparison of timings on two different machines, both using gcc 6.3.0:

```
# on desktop with Intel-Core-i7-4930K-Processor-12M-Cache-up-to-3_90-GHz
g++ loop_test.cpp -o loop_test -std=c++11 -O3
./loop_test 
vector time = 12.3742 s
scalar time = 10.7406 s

g++ loop_test.cpp -o loop_test -std=c++11 -O3 -ffast-math
./loop_test 
vector time = 11.2543 s
scalar time = 5.70873 s


# on mac with Intel-Core-i5-4258U-Processor-3M-Cache-up-to-2_90-GHz
g++ loop_test.cpp -o loop_test -std=c++11 -O3
./loop_test 
vector time = 2.89193 s
scalar time = 1.87269 s

g++ loop_test.cpp -o loop_test -std=c++11 -O3 -ffast-math
./loop_test 
vector time = 2.38422 s
scalar time = 0.995433 s
```

By all means the first machine is superior in terms of cache size, clock speed etc. Still the code runs 5x faster on the second machine.

**Question:**

Can this be explained? Or am I doing something wrong here?

Link to the code: https://gist.github.com/anandpratap/262a72bd017fdc6803e23ed326847643

**Edit**

After comments from ShadowRanger, I added the `__restrict__` keyword to `function_vector` and `-march=native` compilation flag. This gives:

```
# on desktop with Intel-Core-i7-4930K-Processor-12M-Cache-up-to-3_90-GHz
vector time = 1.3767 s
scalar time = 1.28002 s

# on mac with Intel-Core-i5-4258U-Processor-3M-Cache-up-to-2_90-GHz 
vector time = 1.05206 s
scalar time = 1.07556 s
```

Comment: put the code here, not on an external site, otherwise your question risks being closed. If it's long, try to make an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: Are you sure the desktop is not part of any distributed computing cluster? Was it idle when you started the task?

Comment: It's my personal machine. I just re-ran with an average load of 0.12 before starting the run, so pretty idle I would say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Odds are possible pointer aliasing is limiting optimizations in the vectorized case.

Try changing the declaration of `function_vector` to:

```
void function_vector(double *__restrict__ x, double *__restrict__ y, double *__restrict__ z, const int n){
```

to use [`g++`'s non-standard support](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Restricted-Pointers.html) for a feature matching [C99's `restrict` keyword](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/restrict).

Without it, `function_vector` likely has to assume that the writes to `x[i]` could be modifying values in `y` or `z`, so it can't do read-ahead to get the values.

Comment: Note: This assumes `g++` is treating references as implicitly restricted and/or inlining `function_scalar` which would give it the information to know they're not aliased. You'd have to check the assembly to verify which (if any) it's actually doing.

Comment: Thanks, including `__restrict__` leads to almost same time for the vector and the scalar case. However, I still don't get such a drastic difference between the two machines.

Comment: I think the OP asks why the stunning difference between the Mac i5 vs. the beefy i7. If the tasks was I/O bound I'd suspect the superior excellent I/O throughput if Mac's NVMe SSDs. But this is CPU bound so I'm stunned so far.

Comment: @maverick: Ah, I glossed over the hardware differences. That said, the question doesn't specify the OS of the "desktop", or the compiler version on either; it could easily be a compiler difference, a quirk in the default flags, etc. Even if the compilers are the same, it could also be that the portable instructions are slower on the new CPU for some arcane reason; you might try passing `-march=native` to the compiler on each to ensure it's using appropriate instructions for the CPU in question. You'd also need to check bus speeds (this does a lot of memory read/write).

Comment: Oh, and make sure power conservation settings are disabled (run at 100% regardless of load); if one machine is constantly throttling the CPU (e.g. every time you block on the bus to memory), you'd see a meaningful performance loss.

Comment: Sorry, I did mention the version but did not highlight it but wow --march=native on the i7 made it almost 5x faster. I never used that flag before. It is weird though, I would expect it to work by default.  On I5 I have macos sierra and on i7 I have ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: @maverick: Blech, sorry. I clearly can't read tonight, see the version now. And yeah, `-march=native` can massively improve performance (at the expense of portability of course). `-mtune` can be used to generate code that's optimal on a given architecture without sacrificing portability (usually makes larger code of course), so that's also an option. In any event, when you're talking about vectorizing code, you definitely want `-march` or `-mtune`; without it, the compiler can't actually use the modern vector instructions introduced post SSE2 (the minimum baseline on x86-64).

Comment: It's possible Mac OSX (knowing what sort of hardware it needs to support, given Mac doesn't do third party hardware) might be automatically tuning for the native hardware, which would explain why it's fast regardless.

Comment: @maverick, didn't you indicate in the edit to your question that this doesn't change the fact that the faster i7 performs slower? so i'm not sure why it's marked as the answer.

Comment: It was the 5x difference that actually bothered me. I would think that the small difference that now exists can be due to differences between the two machines. So ShadowRangers comment of using `-march=native` seems to solve that.